# broken pipe between cat and grep on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I am trying to read the wireless connection link quality in a C program.

I do:

```
for(;;){
    rf_line = popen("cat /proc/net/wireless | grep wlan0", "r");
    fgets(line, 80, rf_line);
    pclose(rf_line);
    ...
    //more code
}
```

On the Raspberry Pi with the Wheezy 08/12 image, it crashes with the errno 32, broken pipe.
If I call `cat /proc/net/wireless | grep wlan0` from the console, it works fine.

Also if I am trying to debug with gdb, the error does not occur.
On my Laptop with Linux Mint 14 it does never occur.

I tried to prevent this by making a `system(...)` call. Even with opening a new bash with `bash -c ...`.
I also tried, not to write to the stdout and into a file, without luck.

edit:
with
    `rf_line = popen("/bin/grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless", "r");`

Increasing the size of the line to 200 had no effect.

I have the same result, errno 32.

edit:
with
     `rf_line = fopen("/proc/net/wireless","r");`

I have the same result, errno 32.

This however leads to the suggestion, that popen does not work correctly, because it is the only pipe left.
Fopen / popen is called very frequently, could this be the issue?

Has anybody a clou, what I could do next?

regards,
Ck

Comment: How far did your program come? Have you got a `line` and have you called `pclose()`?

Comment: when I do it in gdb, every breakpoint is hit and I get the correct line. If I clear the breakpoints and continue, the pipe breaks before the end of popen.

Comment: @konsolebox it had no effect.

Comment: Popen is called very frequently, could this be an issue?

Comment: @ChristophKuhr Does your call with popen work just even once?

Comment: No, on the first run it breaks.Perhaps the second call destroys the pipe somehow? this is what it looks like to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 2 write`:

**EPIPE**: fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed. When this happens the writing process will also receive a **SIGPIPE** signal. (Thus, the write return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)

So the command, that you executed with `popen("...")` (not your program) will get the EPIPE error on it's `write()` and the SIGPIPE signal if you close your end of the pipe before it finishes to write anything.

You need to read every line of the command output, not just first one. Until you'll get EOF.

Comment: +1 I actually found the definition in one of the header files but I didn't know its specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how popen works but try. Perhaps it just doesn't work with pipes.

```
rf_line = popen("grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless", "r");
```

Another is to add absolute path like:

```
rf_line = popen("/bin/grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless", "r");
```

Or

```
rf_line = popen("/usr/bin/grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless", "r");
```

**UPDATE**

This one worked for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char line[200];
    line[0] = '\0';
    FILE* rf_line = popen("grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless", "r");
    fgets(line, 200, rf_line);
    printf("%s", line);  /* You can remove this */
    pclose(rf_line);
}
```

Comment: BTW, you could avoid depending on `grep` and simply read each line of `/proc/net/wireless` thru `fopen` and use `strstr` on it.